# reading non-english html pages with c#

Tags: html, unicode, hebrew

I am trying to find a string in Hebrew in a website. The reading code is attached.

Afterward I try to read the file using streamReader but I can't match strings in other languages.
what am I suppose to do?

```
   // used on each read operation
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

    // prepare the web page we will be asking for
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
        WebRequest.Create("http://www.webPage.co.il");

    // execute the request
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
        request.GetResponse();

    // we will read data via the response stream
    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    string tempString = null;
    int count = 0;
    FileStream fileDump = new FileStream(@"c:\dump.txt", FileMode.Create);
    do
    {
        count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        fileDump.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);

    }
    while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

    fileDump.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing appropriate encoder, take a look at [WebResponse.GetResponseStream Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) for details

Updated: Use Hebrew (Windows) encoding is 1255

```
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255); // Hebrew (Windows) 

// Pipe the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
 StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader( resStream , encode );
```

Comment: still nothing...

I think my problem might be with the string searched, I mean I can't just match:

str.contains("other language code"); 

right?
what am I suppose to do?

Comment: I tried to encode the searched message but it failed too

string messageToFind = "otherLanguage";

        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

        Byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(messageToFind);

        messageToFind = encodedBytes.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

The problem was choosing the wrong encoding, I chose utf-8 which isn't always the right answer :)

key lines:

```
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255");
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);
```

Comment: Please, edit you initial question and add this as your solution for others with the same problem.